# Make subfolder main folder - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

On my host I have created a folder called "xyz-wp". Inside "xyz-wp" I have installed wordpress site, because doesn't want to stop the main site until the wordpress site is finished. Add the index.php and .htaccess outside the wordpress folder. "xyz-wp/index.php".

My question now is that how can I make that when user search example: http://www.example.com to make as main folder "xyz-wp/index.php" in Wordpress, not take the index.php on the root folder but take from "xyz-wp/index.php"

Comment: do you want to redirect the users of the site to new wordpress site ?

Comment: Using the following code on .httaccess the website is redirect to the folder and everything works fine:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ xyz-wp [L]

But the URL still is "http://www.example.com/xyz-wp". I need to be only "http://example.com"

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_Directories_On_Your_Existing_Server

Comment: I check that @NathanDawson, but there is no solution about the domain name

Comment: Please see points 4 and 5.

Comment: Now my wordpress URL is : http://example.com/xyz-wp/wordpress
and Site Address: http://example.com/xyz-wp. Do you think that if I change  Site Address to: http://example.com it will work ? @NathanDawson

Comment: I think if you follow the steps outlined there and also http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory you'll get it working the way it should be.

Comment: would you not just change your apache config to point at the new folder instead of the old one?